# ViewPager image slider with ArrayList

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Am trying to make an image slider whose number of images depends on how many images the user has uploaded. I tried checking multiple tutorials but I keep getting the same error (the images won't load, and the app crashes when I click on the pager or try to slide it)
Here is the custom PagerAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> images;

public ImageAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> images) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    Picasso.get().load(images.get(position)).into(imageView);
    container.addView(imageView,0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((ImageView) object);

}
```

}

Here is the activity code

```
private ArrayList<String> images;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

    images = new ArrayList<>();

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

   

}
```

I have some code that is successfully getting the download URLs from firebase and adding them to the arrayList.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Unfortunately my pc is too slow to successfully run the app on the emulator i have been trying the past two days its the biggest app i have tried to develop so far

Comment: Without an error log, we can't guess the issue. @BrynePhiri please provide reason for crash